# How to check column type using libpqxx?

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I am using `libpqxx` in my project. The project is specific because I do not know what SQL statements will be executed. Lets say user input statement:

`SELECT * FROM table1`

Executing that statement I get result records and I can iterate trough it.

```
for( auto row = myresult.begin(); row != myresult.end(); ++row)
{
    //Here I can access row elements.
}
```

If I know what is `type` of first element in `row`, lets say it is `int`, I can get value as:

```
int firstElement = row[0].as<int>();
```

But I do not know that. There is method `type()` (I can call it on row element) and it `return`s type `oid` (It is some kind of column identifier) it is numerical value, but I do not know how to use that value to get type of row element. My question is:

Is there some enumeration or some other way to use this `oid` to get row element `type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oid is internal to postgres. not libpqxx.
Just type

```
select typname, oid from pg_type;
```

in psql.This lists all the avilable types.

If you want to use types from a source file, get postgres source.
http://doxygen.postgresql.org/include_2catalog_2pg__type_8h_source.html

just look at this config in go for a clean look. Ignore T_(one underscore) in the name of types.

https://github.com/olt/libpq/blob/master/oid/types.go

Comment: Returns 408 rows of null...